# QListView in edit mode eats first mous click

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside2

I have [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html) with an item delegate that animates when the mouse hovers over it.
This is done via a delegate using a custom widget and popping the index under the cursor into edit mode like so (mouse tracking is activated on the list view):

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if index.isValid():
        # start playing playing under cursor
        self.edit(index)
```

This works fine and I have a mechanism for closing the editor as well to ensure only one item is ever playing as the mouse moves around the list view.
The issue now is that the drag&drop behaviour has suffered - but only under windows and linux, it works fine on OSX.

To use the default drag behaviour of my [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html) I use the [mousePressEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent) to close the editor when the left mouse button is clicked like this:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if self.currentEditor:
        try:
            # clean up open editor
            self.currentEditor.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
            self.closeEditor(self.currentEditor, QtGui.QAbstractItemDelegate.NoHint)
            self.commitData(self.currentEditor)
            self.setFocus()
        except RuntimeError:
            # no current editor. click happened outside the thumbnails
            pass

    super(ElementView, self).mousePressEvent(event)
```

The last line is the call to the parent class to let it start it's regular drag event.

On OSX I can hover over the item to make it play, then click&drag to drag it away. On windows I have to click twice without moving the mouse before the same happens.
I have tried setting the view's [setState()](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setState) to ensure the view is not in edit state. I have also tried setting focus on the view explicitly firs thing in the [mousePressEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent) but neither seem to help.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[EDIT] It's not related to the drag as I am experiencing the same issue with the context menu. On windows I have to right click twice to open it, on OSX it works fine. I have edited the title to be more specific now.

frank

Comment: please, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Will do as soon as I find the time. I had hoped that this was a common issue that somebody might identify quickly. Sorry for not providing one in the first place, I was running out of time to post this last night.